# How to detect this image using OpenCV? (In real time on a iOS device)

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I've been trying for a while to detect an image that looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately i haven't been very lucky.

This image has to be detected so that I can "crop" a scene to whatever is below it.

I've been trying different feature detectors, like ORB, FAST and BRISK. And although I'm getting some key-points that look promising, when I try to find the Homography and apply the perspective transform to calculate my "scene corners" the results make absolutely no sense.

I suspect that the issue might be in how "simple" the marker is? since the corner points of the image are like technically the same, and within the small triangle in the middle, they are also very alike.

I'm looking for an advice or suggestion in how to approach this problem.

---

Edit:

My object to detect is an image. But the scene to be detected in is the video feed from an iOS camera device.

---

Edit 2:

I've replaced the top image with something more complex hoping the increase in keypoints would finally allow me to detect the object, but still no luck.

Here is the new top image:

[image]

And this is a sample of a frame: (taken as a screenshot of the iphone screen)

[image]

Keypoints detected:
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a sample input frame as well?

Comment: hello, sure just did. I also updated the image to be searched, but still no luck =(

Comment: No images visible

Comment: You should try making non-redundant patterns in the image. Try making the background with random dark/light lines instead of just plain black (I guess that is possible? )

Comment: maybe you could grab some existing snippet for QR code rcognition? http://dsynflo.blogspot.de/2014/10/opencv-qr-code-detection-and-extraction.html